# Using Find function to find a value then setting a range with it

Tags: excel, vba

The error is in the line starting with range, it should copy that range and paste it after the last row. It is currently saying an object is required. I was originally using .address on the FinClass line but that did not help with the error.

```
Sub MatrixSize()

Dim ValuesRange As Range
Dim NumClass As Integer

LastColumn = Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowG = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

i = 5
'from the first class Ta total to the last
Do Until Cells(i, "G") = LastRowG
Set TestValue = Cells(i, "G")

'Find the number of times the value shows
Set rng = Range(Cells(7, "Q"), Cells(LastRow, "Q"))
NumClass = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, TestValue)

'if numclass is not the correct value paste more
If NumClass <> Cells(i, "H") Then
'find the location of the Te
FinClass = Range(Cells(7, "Q"), Cells(LastRow, "Q")).Find(What:=TestValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
'copy the row that contains the test values from it to the final column
Range(FinClass, Cells(FinClass.Row, LastColumn.Column)).Copy

'Starting at the final row pasted the copy value
Range(LastRow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial

Else
'test next value
i = i + 1

End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Start by `Dim FinClass As Range`, then `Set FinClass  = Range(...).Find(...)`, then test with the `Find` succeeded with `If Not FinClass Is Nothing Then`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub MatrixSize()
Dim LastColumn As Long, LastRow As Long, LastRowG As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim FinClass As Range
Dim ValuesRange As Range
Dim NumClass As Integer

LastCol = Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowG = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

i = 5
'from the first class Ta total to the last
Do Until Cells(i, "G") = ""
TestValue = Cells(i, "G")

'Find the number of times the value shows
Set rng = Range(Cells(7, "Q"), Cells(LastRow, "Q"))
NumClass = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, TestValue)

'if numclass is not the correct value paste more
If NumClass <> Cells(i, "H") Then
'find the location of the Te
Set FinClass = Range(Cells(7, "Q"), Cells(LastRow, "Q")).Find(What:=TestValue) '.Address
'copy the row that contains the test values from it to the final column
  
'r = Range(FinClass, Cells(FinClass.Row, Cells(FinClass.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Copy

   iCol = Cells(FinClass.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - FinClass.Column + 1
    If iCol < 1 Then iCol = 1
    Set FinClass = FinClass.Resize(1, iCol)
FinClass.Copy Destination:=Cells(LastRow, "Q")

LastRow = LastRow + 1

Else
'test next value
i = i + 1
End If

Loop

End Sub
```